# Second HTML option load by default

Tags: html, html-select

In an HTML select element, is it possible to have the second option selected by default?

```
<select class="styled" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="9u.html">Team 9u</option>
    <option value="10u.html">Team 10u</option>
    <option value="11u.html">Team 11u</option>
    <option value="12u.html">Team 12u</option>
    <option value="13u.html">Team 13u</option>
    <option value="14u.html">Team 14u</option>
    <option value="15u.html">Team 15u</option>
    <option value="16u.html">Team 16u</option>
</select>
```

I would like the value "10u" to be in the select box when I load the page.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A search for `html select option load by default` would have given you the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: <option value="10u.html" selected>Team 10u</option>

Comment: And as another remark, you shouldn't do inline javascript, it's evil :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the selected attribute. Is google down?

```
<option value="10u.html" selected>Team 10u</option>
```

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Haha I should really keep sarcasm out of answers, but sometimes I just can't help it.

Comment: Is it a good idea to add selected to the first element? Even though its not needed?

Comment: @BrettMerrifield No, the first option is selected by default, and it's not considered best practice to add the `selected` attribute to the first element (nor is it frowned upon, but it adds unnecessary code bloat).